# What is difference between binding to attribute and binding to property in Angular?

Tags: angular, data-binding, attr

I understand that when we bind to data attributes, we need to use the syntax `[attr.data-something]="expression"`
But why do we need to bind to, for example, `id, title, name` in the same way?
Doesn't binding to a property (without `attr.`) give the same result?

```
<input type="text" [attr.title]="expression" />
<input type="text" [title]="expression" />
```

Asking because I saw this in the source code of some popular projects. For example PrimeNG:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSqie.png)

Couldn't find a clear answer anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a behaviour difference when used on an Angular component.

- `[title]` will bind to the `title` input if there is one but won't add the title attribute.
- `[attr.title]` will only apply a `title` attribute to your element.

Comment: It's true. But do I understand correctly that when applied to native elements, such as <input />, there is no difference at all?

Comment: Yes indeed, there is no difference !